# Does anti-aliasing have any effect in The Evil Within?

Tags: pc, the-evil-within

On my machine The Evil Within's anti-aliasing settings (off, FXAA, MLAA, SMAA) have seemingly no effect and I suspect AA doesn't work in the first place. I can't notice any difference between no AA and any other form of AA.
I have "applied" graphics settings after changing.

Answer (score 1):

[`r_skipglare 1` command](https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/The_Evil_Within#Console_commands) disables post-processing, including anti-aliasing. Verify if you are using the command. Anti-aliasing in the game works.